# Launching AIR app in secondary monitor

Tags: flash, air

Is there a mechanism by which an AIR application can manually display in whichever monitor I choose?  I can look at the display list in Screen.screens, but I'm unclear on how to actually force the drawing of the app into one of those.

Comment: Since AIR is hardware agnostic, I would assume that it has no knowledge of the number of screens. Thus it would not be possible to select a specific screen.

Comment: no, but it gives you the list of screens and you can pick based on the one that's biggest, which is really the point... I mean, if someone happens to have attached a monitor smaller than the laptop display to their machine... you get my drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you pick the screen that you want from the list provided by the Screen class, set the window x and y coordinates to something inside the bounds of that screen.

The origin of the virtual desktop space is at the top, left-hand corner of the "main" screen (however the OS defines main). Screens above and to the left have negative offsets.

Comment: window? Is that a top level object? or a child of something? Sorry... I probably should just go look it up, but as long as you mentioned it. I've just never heard of window in Flash

Comment: I'm refering to the NativeWindow class in AIR (Flash's twin sister). An AIR app can have any number of windows and each has its own stage.